# Does uniqueness always hold for the Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

[Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem (KET)](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118638/11768) implies the existence and uniqueness of a product measure given its finite-dimensional distributions (FDDs), provided that the latter are consistent. KET puts some restrictions on underlying measurable spaces.

**Question:** I deal with the case of general measurable spaces, so that I cannot apply KET. Suppose, I am *given* a certain product probability measure $\mu$ - so that I know for sure that there exists a product measure for FDDs of $\mu$ (e.g. $\mu$ itself). Can it happen that there exists a probability measure $\nu\neq\mu$ with the same FDDs?

I think, the answer is negative: FDDs are restrictions of $\mu$ to a class of measurable rectangles that generate the product $\sigma$-algebra. Since this class is closed under finite intersections, and $\mu$ agrees with $\nu$ on this class, then $\mu= \nu$. Plainly speaking, only the existence part of KET may be violated in general measurable spaces, not the uniqueness one. Please tell me whether I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two probability measures agree on a $\pi$-system, they agree (see e.g. Th'm 1.7.1 in [these notes](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm3.pdf)) on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $\pi$-system. So, if I've understood correctly, you are done, since $\mu=\nu$ on the $\pi$-system of finite dimensional cylinders generating the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually the way also given in the OP. If you confirm it's correct that's done